# Trigger to update a column during insert in postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have two tables (in postgres) - ads and logs. After every insert into logs table, depending on the action it should increment the count of a column in the ads table.

I have tried to write a function which the trigger will call, but it throws a error while trying to create the function. I am new to postgresql triggers and function, so can someone point out what is wrong with this.

```
create function update_ad_count (action character(4), ad_id INT) returns void 
as $$case when action='VIEW' then
(UPDATE ads SET views = (SELECT views+1 FROM ads WHERE id=ad_id), updated = now() WHERE id=ad_id;)
end;$$
language sql
```

The error I get is

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "case"
LINE 2: as $$case when action=\'VIEW\' then
             ^
```

**Update:**
@Tomalak: Thanks for the function and updating the update statement (couldn't resist the pun).

I learnt after lot of googling, that the function shouldn't have any params and use NEW.col_name and should return a TRIGGER.

Comment: I'm not sure what a function that returns a trigger is. In my understanding, triggers are defined and not returned by functions, but then again I don't know very much about postgres, so I'm glad I got the UPDATE statement right at least. ;-)

Comment: Care to update my answer with your findings, so others that come here through Google find something they can use immediately?

Comment: @Tomalak, if you want to know more about the pseudo-type TRIGGER see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/trigger-definition.html If you still want more info you can ask a new SO question and I'll provide a detailed answer there.

Comment: Oh damn, you can't yet edit other people's posts (sorry I forgot). You can edit your working sample into your own question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your UPDATE call should be:

```
UPDATE ads SET views = views + 1, updated = NOW() WHERE id = ad_id;
```

According to [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createfunction.html), something like this should do it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_ad_count (action CHARACTER(4), ad_id INT) 
RETURNS VOID
AS $$ 
BEGIN
  IF action = 'VIEW' THEN
    UPDATE ads SET views = views + 1, updated = NOW() WHERE id = ad_id;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

CASE is not a flow-control statement, it cannot be used like an IF statement. It is a value-producing statement (an expression) and must be used as such, e.g. you must SELECT/UPDATE from it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not hugely familiar with postgresql, but based on what I do know...  shouldn't it be "$$ case" instead of "$$case"?

Comment: The extra space doesn't work. I think $$ is just an alternative to quote '. It can be used without any space.